# How to run for loop only once using C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I would like to know if there is a way I can run the for loop only once using C#.

Requirement -

I need to perform sum of `n` fields

```
Total = num1 + num2 + num3 + ... + numN
```

I have the list of fields and i can know how many fields will be there based on the length of my list

So i am looking for something like this -

Total no of fields in the list = 3

```
Total = num1 + num2 + num3 // to be run in one go without looping
```

Comment: Maybe look up the LINQ Sum() method if your fields are all within a list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking... Some real code may clarify what you are looking for - please [edit] question with that... I.e. details on what "list of fields" contains and how it related to `num1` would be useful. It somewhat feels you are asking about "loop unrolling" - search and see if that what you need...

Comment: Also make sure you really must limit answers to C# 3... It's quite an old version and people will have hard time sorting out what features are acceptable and which are from newer versions.